# Admob runtime issue - Unity / iOS Build - Rewarded Ad runs once / 2nd run causing issues

Tags: c#, ios, admob, unity-game-engine

hopefully someone can help me sort this anomaly out!

So here's some background info: I'm using a rewarded ad that is triggered when the player dies. This loads a "rewardAd" popup for the player to choose to watch the video for the reward or close the request and it's game over. On the initial run of the game it works perfectly. The reward is to get an extra life and continue playing the game. This also works just fine.

BUT... when the player dies a second time, the "rewardAd" popup is displayed but when the "play ad" button is clicked, the popup disappears, leaving the game in a paused state... From here, the pause button that is still displayed on the screen is active and when clicked will bring up the "pause" popup menu. if the resume game button is clicked, the "rewardAd" popup will display again... And if the "play ad" button is clicked this time, the ad will run again.

So the issue it seems will run the ad the first time the player dies, but will only leave the game in a paused state the second time... Unless you hit the pause button to bring up the "pause" popup menu and then resume from that menu which brings back the "rewardAd" popup again and then this time the ad does load and run again and everything works again.

So my question is, why isn't the video ad loading properly when I die the second time, unless I pause the game (in its already paused state) then resume and get the rewardAd popup a second time and then it will run the ad again.

For some reason it's only reloading the video ad when the "rewardAd" popup is re-triggered twice.

Here's my code for it:

In the Player Class:

```
void fixedUpdate () {
    if (health == 0) {
        helthSprite.fillAmount = 0f;

        GameObject.Find ("RewardAdPopup").GetComponent<TweenAlpha> ().PlayForward ();
        GeneralScript.instance.pauseGame();
    }
}
```

Now the "rewardAdPopup" has two buttons "Play" and "Close" which are attached two these two methods, respectively, in the GeneralScript Class:

```
public void showAd ()
{
    isRewarded = false;
    Admob.Instance ().loadRewardedVideo ("ca-app-pub-3917955116464255/1873040720");
    Admob.Instance ().rewardedVideoEventHandler += onRewardVideoEvent;
    if (Admob.Instance ().isRewardedVideoReady ()) {
        Admob.Instance ().showRewardedVideo ();
    }
}

public void adDeclined ()
{
    Bird.instance.showGameOverPopup ();
}
```

Now I also have the "loadVideo" instance in the "start" method (at the bottom) - otherwise the video would not load even the first time:

```
void Start ()
{
    instance = this;
    if (Application.loadedLevelName.Equals ("GameScene")) {
        InvokeRepeating ("IncreseSpeed", 0f, GameManager.MaxSpawnTime);
    }       
    checkSound ();

    Admob.Instance ().loadRewardedVideo ("ca-app-pub-3917955116464255/1873040720");
}
```

And lastly, the "onRewardVideoEventMethod":

```
void onRewardVideoEvent(string eventName, string message) {

    if (eventName == AdmobEvent.onAdClosed) {

        print ("Ad Closed");
        if (isRewarded) {
            print ("ad watched");
            Bird.instance.health = GameManager.curBirdHealth;
            resumeGame ();
        } else {
            adDeclined ();
        }

    } else if (eventName == AdmobEvent.onRewarded) {
        print ("Ad Rewarded");
        isRewarded = true;


    } else if (eventName == AdmobEvent.adViewWillDismissScreen) {
        if (isRewarded) {
            print("ad dismissed");
            Bird.instance.health = GameManager.curBirdHealth;
            resumeGame ();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm certain lies somewhere in here... Possibly it has to do with the "Play" button's "OnClick" settings in the Unity Inspector under UI Button script, but I'm not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This has me stumped...

Answer (score 0):

Your method `showAd` has the problem in this line

```
public void showAd ()
{
   //.....
   Admob.Instance ().rewardedVideoEventHandler += onRewardVideoEvent;
   //.....
}
```

Every time the ad is played you add another event handler. From the looks of it `Admob.Instance` is a singleton.

Alo as a nother suggestion, use `fixedUpdate` for only physics.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I'm new to all this so my know-how is quite amateur.  So to fix the problem, would it work to use "-=" instead of "+="?

Comment: Also, how would I structure calling the "RewardAdPopup" when the player dies if not where "health=0"? Which is in "fixedUpdate".

Comment: @MishoMilicevic In Unity there is `Update` method and `FixedUpdate` method. FixedUpdate is suggested to be used for physics caluclations.

Comment: @MishoMilicevic For the event handler problem, I would suggest tot use `Awake` or `Start` method, which are called only once in the script`s life cycle and add the eventhandler there.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try and implement that properly and get back to you.

Comment: @MishoMilicevic looking forward to playing your game

Comment: Sungu. Thanks, those tips helped. And I look forward to getting you a copy of my game! So I used an "Update" method to call the "RewardAdPopup" and placed the handler instance in the "Start" method.  This allowed the ad to run over and over with every death which was perfect, but it caused the popups to stay on the screen...so I created a method to dismiss them and added that to the handler method. This fixed the popup issue and everything is working except for one thing...

Comment: On all consequent calls to watch the reward video, I have to click the play button on the "RewardAdPopup" more than once. On the first click I get an xcode console message saying "You're using GoogleMobileAds SDK version 7.18 and to consider updating" (which I did to v.7.20 but it still says that mesage)... And another click will give me the message, "2017-06-16 23:57:04.353415-0700 ablb[1465:558089] <Google> Ignoring request. Another request is already in progress."... But click a couple times and the video will start again.  So just this one issue left.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @MishoMilicevic We can talk over Stackoverflow's chat to have a better understanding of the problem of the code

Comment: I'd love to! But unfortunately, I'm new here and it says I don't have enough reputation to chat yet.